# Gradient points in the direction of greatest change

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, intuition, alternative-proof

[image]

Can anyone provide me with an alternative, possibly more intuitive proof of this proposition? I'm confused with where $cos\theta$ has come from?

Comment: The $\cos$ is from the very definition of scalar product in Euclidean space, and its equivalency with projection (given vectors $a,b$, $a\cdot b=|a||b|\cos \theta$, with $\theta$ the angle between $a$ and $b$) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product